# File uploading not working on Win phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, upload, dotnet-httpclient

I have a app in which user can record video and an api to upload recorded video to azure.
I am using below code

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.MaxRequestContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) 
       { 
            MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue
       })
{
    MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(chunks), "file", fileName);
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

This is working only when video is less than of 10 sec. When I tried to upload video of size around 20-30 MB than it fails.
In response I got status code 404.

I also tried another way to upload. But result was same error:

```
string boundary = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary;

        StringBuilder header = new StringBuilder();
        header.Append("\r\n--");
        header.Append(boundary);
        header.Append("\r\n");
        header.Append("Content-Disposition: file; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n");
        header.Append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n");
        byte[] headerbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header.ToString());

        StringBuilder footer = new StringBuilder();
        footer.Append("\r\n--");
        footer.Append(boundary);
        footer.Append("--\r\n");
        byte[] footerbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(footer.ToString());

        using (var streamWriter = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            streamWriter.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);              
            streamWriter.Write(footerbytes, 0, footerbytes.Length);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the web.config of your web.api site, in particular this section

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The xxx is in KB.

Comment: I just confirmed it from api developer, he said that max length limits to 60 MB. But in my case I got error even with 30 MB.

Comment: @mayank.karki, can you capture the request using Burp/fiddler on both WP and iOS/Android and post the headers for comparison?